# Swift REPL throws python error?

Tags: python, xcode, swift, read-eval-print-loop

When I try running the swift REPL using `swift` or `xcrun swift`, I get the following Python error:

> Hristos-MacBook-Pro:~ Hristo$ swift
>
> Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
>
> Abort trap: 6

It looks like Swift's REPL was written in Python. I recently installed `pip`, which might have broken something. I am using Xcode 6.1 (A1052d) and OS X Yosemite. What could be the case?

[image: Trying to run <code>swift</code>]

Comment: Is it definitely running Apple's Swift REPL and not some python program? What is the output of running `which swift`?

Comment: It says `/usr/bin/swift`. The same python error is given by `xcrun swift`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the active python version (previously python 2.7 installed via macports) and it worked:

```
sudo port select python python33
```

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into the same problem.  The above answer gave me a hint for a non-invasive solution (in my case I have fink's python at the head of the path)

```
% PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
% swift
```

This solution is based upon the following observations.  Fink (and I presume Macports and possibly other third-party python providers) put their bin directories at the head of the path.  This can be seen by invoking python on the command line:

```
% which python
/sw/bin/python
```

This is where I ran into the problem that lead me to search for a solution:

```
% swift
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
[1]    19219 abort      swift
```

By changing the $PATH variable at the shell level, the problem is avoided without changing the default condition for future shell sessions:

```
% PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
% which python
/usr/bin/python
```

So now it works:

```
% swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
   1>
```

A more permanent solution (short of permanently changing the order of the $PATH variable elements) might be to include in one's shell dotfile the following alias (or equivalent function):

```
alias swift="PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH swift"
```

Comment: @smci.  I disagree.  This provides an alternate approach that does not permanently change the configuration of the computer.

Comment: Does swift take its Python from the system path... you'd need to explain why. Then if my closevote is wrong I'll retract it.

Comment: Here is the evidence:  zsh-% which python
/sw/bin/python
zsh-% swift
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
[1]    19219 abort      swift
zsh-% PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
zsh-% which python
/usr/bin/python
zsh-% swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1>